# Send UDP from Android Emulator to Host PC

Tags: android, udp, emulation

I'm trying to send UDP packets from an emulated device (Nexus S 4.0", 480 x 800: hdpi) to my host PC for development and testing. The sending side seems correct and doesn't encounter any errors, but Wireshark indicates they are not arriving at the host PC. I've researched this problem and all the fixes that worked for others are not working for me:

- I added "uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" to the maifest XML file. (I also have ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE but I don't think that's necessary for this.)
- I am sending the packets to the host loopback address 10.0.2.2. The port is 5006, so it's not one that I should need special privileges for.
- I am calling DatagramSocket.send() in a dedicated thread, not in the main thread. (I think this would throw NetworkOnMainThreadException anyway, and I'm not getting any exceptions.)
- I have Telnet-ed into "localhost 5444" and issued the "redir add udp:5006:5006" command to setup UDP port forwarding on the emulator's virtual router. The command returns "OK" without error, and "redir list" returns "udp:5006  => 5006".
- I've also setup UDP port forwarding (port 5006) on my host PC's router (between PC and open internet). But I don't think that should be necessary, this router is not between the emulator and the host PC.
- I have disabled Windows firewall and anti-virus on the host PC.

Here is the relevant code in my MainActivity.java. The start() and stop() methods are called from button clicks (omitted because they are not part of the problem):

```
private static String TAG = "MainActivity";
private volatile boolean running = false;
private String ip = "10.0.2.2";
private int port = 5006;

public void start(View view) {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            byte[] bytes = "Hi from UDPSender!".getBytes();
            try {
                InetAddress inetAddr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
                running = true;

                while (running == true) {
                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(bytes, bytes.length, inetAddr, port);
                    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                    socket.setBroadcast(false);
                    socket.send(packet);
                    socket.close();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Send packet to "+packet.getAddress().getHostAddress()+":"+packet.getPort());
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

public void stop(View view) {
    running = false;        
}
```